# Breaking a Set into a List of Sets

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a text file and turn the pair of numbers inside the file into a list of sets.

Here is what my text file looks like:

```
4 #Number of pairs  
1 2
4 5
2 3
3 4
```

I've been able to turn the data from the text file into a list and then convert it into set but I end up getting a massive set instead of a list of sets like I would like.

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    data = f.read().splitlines()

set_of_pairs = set(data)
print(set_of_pairs)
```

Current Output:

```
{'1 2', '2 3', '4 5', '3 4'}
```

Desired Output:

```
[{'1 2'}, {'2 3'}, {'4 5'}, {'3 4'}]
```

Comment: you can try `[{x} for x in set_of_pairs]` but order won't be preserved. Does it matter? if it does, don't create a set with the values in the first place...

Comment: so you want each set to contain one **`string`** item?

Comment: Frankly, the data structure that looks right to me is a list of tuples of ints: `[tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in f]` giving: `[(1, 2), (4, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4)]`

Comment: And I would just do `next(f)` rather than `first_line = f.readline()`.  It seems all the first line does is tell you how many pairs of numbers you are going to have which you don't really need.  If you need to find out how many pairs you processed just take the `len()` of your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a list of one-element sets (which doesn't seem too useful), you can write:

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    data = f.read().splitlines()

set_of_pairs = [{line} for line in data]
print(set_of_pairs) #=> [{'1 2'}, {'2 3'}, {'4 5'}, {'3 4'}]
```

However, it seems more likely that you would want a list of sets containing two integers each, as in:

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    data = f.read().splitlines()

set_of_pairs = [{int(n) for n in line.split()} for line in data]
# Note that the order of pairs is not guaranteed
print(set_of_pairs) #=> [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {3, 4}]
```

Or even a list of tuples:

```
Input_File = input("Enter your file: ").lower()
with open(Input_File, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    data = f.read().splitlines()

set_of_pairs = [tuple(line.split()) for line in data]
print(set_of_pairs) #=> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (3, 4)]
```